# return false not working on form submit in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function SaleProduct() {   
      var CusId=$('#CusId').val(); 
      $.get('customer-id.php?CusId='+CusId, function(data) {
         if(data==0){
     alert("Customer Id not valid.")
     return false;
   }
        });
     }
```

```html
<form action="sales-edit-insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="return SaleProduct()">
  <input type="text" name="CusId" id="CusId"/>
  <!--Some input field here-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

return false; or e.preventDefault(); not working on above function when I submit the form. Form is submitted after showing an alert.

Comment: From where you are calling this function "SaleProduct"

Comment: <form action="sales-edit-insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="return SaleProduct()">
  <!--Some input field here-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

Comment: you return false from async callback

Comment: You use jquery. Why not use listeners to prevent default action and form submission ?

Comment: remove the action and do the navigation after validation on success of the async call.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SaleProduct` returns nothing(actually `undefined`).
You can stop immediate form sending with `return false;` inside of `onsubmit` attribute:

```
<form action="sales-edit-insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="SaleProduct(); return false;">
```

And later you can submit your form manually:

```
function SaleProduct() {   
  var form = ...;
  var CusId=$('#CusId').val(); 
  $.get('customer-id.php?CusId='+CusId, function(data) {
    if(data==0){
      alert("Customer Id not valid.")
      return;
    }
    form.submit();
  });
  return false; // you can also move this statement to here from attribute
}
```

---

Most simple way to get form element is provide it into `onsubmit`:

```
<form action="sales-edit-insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkCustomer(this)">
```

And js:

```
function checkCustomer(form) {
  //code from above
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If data!=0 then form should be submit. But form not submit by using above script

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery already so why bother with the `onsubmit` attribute. Try

```
<form action="sales-edit-insert.php" method="post" id="sale-product-form">
```

and

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#sale-product-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var form = this;
    $.get('customer-id.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
      if (data == 0) {
        alert('Customer Id not valid.')
      } else {
        form.submit() // submit normally
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If data!=0 then form should be submit. But form not submit by using above script

Comment: @RajuChowdhury that's vital information you should have included in your question

Comment: @RajuChowdhury I've updated my answer to submit the form normally